# how to match a sentence having particular word in different patterns

Tags: regex, python-2.7

We have a problem here...
We have a text having different patterns of sentences.
We want to get the sentence having a particular word.
Eg:

> One further point, by way of providing another model. The analysis in
>   the second paragraph could lead in the following direction. 'The
>   **Destructors**' deals with, obviously, destruction, whilst the book of
>   Genesis deals with creation. The vocabulary is similar: Blackie
>   notices that 'chaos had advanced', an ironic reversal of God's
>   imposing of form on a void. Furthermore, the phrase 'streaks of light
>   came in through the closed shutters where they worked with the
>   seriousness of creators', used in the context of destruction, also
>   parodies the creation of light and darkness in the early passages of
>   the Biblical book. Greene's ironic use of the vocabulary of the Bible
>   might be making the point that, for him, the Second World War
>   signalled the end of a particular Christian era. Now, it is perfectly
>   arguable that the rise of fascism is linked to this, or that it is the
>   cause. The cult of personality and secular leadership has, for Greene,
>   taken over from the key role of the church in Western societies. In
>   this way the two main themes identified above - the tension between
>   individual and community, and religion - are linked. In terms of essay
>   writing this link could well be made after the discussion of the theme
>   of the individual and the community, and its links with the theme of
>   leadership. This might be the general conclusion to the essay. After
>   thoughtful consideration and interpretation a student may well decide
>   that this is what the **(destructors.)**' boils down to: Greene is making a
>   clear link between the rise of fascism and the decline of the Church's
>   influence. Despite the fact that fascism has been recently defeated,
>   Greene sees the lack of any contemporary values which could provide
>   social cohesion as providing the potential for its reappearance.

In the above text, we have bold words (destructors). We want to get the sentences which are having the word "destructors".
The word "destructors" can be present in different formats. Eg: `(destructors), (DesTrucTors), (Des.tructors), DESTRUCTORS, destructors, des-tructors`.
When we tried writing a regex to match the sentences, we are failing to get the sentences at some conditions(like we are getting half sentences, etc.,).

Could you please help us with this.
If this information doesn't help you to solve, please let us know. Will update it.
Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure about Python, but I believe this might work:

```
for match in re.finditer(r"[^.]*destructors[^.]*\.[^\w\s]*", subject, re.IGNORECASE):
# match start: match.start()
# match end (exclusive): match.end()
# matched text: match.group()
```

In any case, I think the regex you want is:

```
[^.]*destructors[^.]*\.[^\w\s]*
```

with the case insensitive and global flags set.

Comment: @jailfroid Thank you very much. But we got one more situation. We are having "." in middle of sentences also. Then the above regex is matching half of the sentence.  
Eg: `'In the Fig. 1A, the Destructors' deals with, obviously, destruction, whilst the book of Genesis deals with creation.`   
In the above eg, the output should be `In the .....creation.`  But we are getting from `1A .... creation.`
Please help me with this issue.  
Thank you!!!

Comment: OK, try: `re.search(r"(?:[^.]|\.(?:\S|\s+[^A-Z]))*destructors[^.]*\.[^\w\s]*", subject, re.IGNORECASE)`. This searches for anything that is NOT a full stop OR a full stop NOT followed by anything that is not a space or one or more spaces not followed by capital letters A-Z...

Comment: @Jailfroid Thank you very much. Finally, it works... I have made some changes to it. I changed like following: `(?:[^.]|\.(?:\S|\s+[^A-Z]))*destructors(?:[^.]|\.(?:\S|\s+[^A-Z]))*\.[^\w\s]*`. Then it worked perfectly.

Comment: Hi @Jaifroid,
The above condition worked well, but at one instance it failed to get the sentence. TEXT: `A grid of custom graphite-impregnated silicon markers was placed on the bursal surface of the bone and tendon to measure tissue motion during the mechanical testing (Fig. \xe2\x80\x8b(Fig.3).\xe2\x80\x8b(Fig.3).3(Fig.3).3).` I need to check match with `(Fig.3).3` pattern. I used above regex: `(?:[^.]|\.(?:\S|\s+[^A-Z]))*(Fig.3).3(?:[^.]|\.(?:\S|\s+[^A-Z]))*\.[^\w\s]*`. But at the output I got only  `(Fig.3).3(Fig.3).3).` this text instead of sentence. Please help me with this. Thank you!!!

Comment: Well it matches the whole sentence if you just do:

Comment: Well it matches the whole sentence if you just do:
`(?:[^.]|\.(?:\S|\s+[^A-Z]))*Fig.3(?:[^.]|\.(?:\S|\s+[^A-Z]))*\.[^\w\s]*`
The problem with your version is the parentheses, which have a special meaning in Regular Expressions (they mean capture groups. If you really need only a sentence that contains "(Fig.3).3" in parentheses, then you can put backslashes before the parentheses, and also before the periods, like this:
`(?:[^.]|\.(?:\S|\s+[^A-Z]))*\(Fig\.3\)\.3(?:[^.]|\.(?:\S|\s+[^A-Z]))*\.[^\w\s]*`
Remember a . (period) means any character in regex. You have to do \. to match period.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!
But I am using re.escape(str_match) in the code, when I did that the regex looks like: `\\(Fig\\.3\\)\\.3`. It is also escaping the parentheses and I didn't get any answer. But when I used your regex(`\(Fig\.3\)\.3`) it worked and I got the answer. What is the difference between both? Thank you...

Comment: It looks like you're not escaping the parenthesis with `\\(Fig\\.3\\)\\.3`. You're in fact escaping the backslash. `\\\` means a literal backslash. The second backslash becomes literal rather than acting as an escape character, therefore the parenthesis is unescaped. Use a single backslash to escape a special character such as parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful if you could provide the regex pattern which you have tried with so far. The best I can come up with is,

```
str_text='your text here containing DESTRUCTORS'
match=re.search('pass all the destructors combination here', str_text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Try for more patterns available for string formatting with regex here,https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: We have tried the following regex's:
- `re.findall('\.\s(.*?[Dd]estructors\.?.*?)\.', subject)`, `[^.]*destructors[^.]*\.`, `[^.]*(?:destructors)\.`, `\s[^A-Z].+?(?:destructors).+?\)\.`. We used the solution given by @Jaifroid, but when we have ` . ` in middle of sentences, the condition is failing. Is there any method to resolve this issue ?. Thank you!!!